# XML Schema: How to require at least one element B for every element A?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I am writing an XML Schema file based on a collection of XML files. One requirement that I am supposed to implement is that for each element A, there must be at least one element B with matching data.

For example if there is an element A in the xml file like this:

```
<peanutButterCode>A001</peanutButterCode>
```

There must be at least one matching element B in that file like this:

```
<jellyCode>A001</jellyCode>
```

Any thoughts on how to implement such a requirement, so that any xml file that has an element A with no corresponding element B fails validation?

Edit: More specifically speaking, below is a simplified XML Schema code snippet that I will use to illustrate my problem. It seems big but this is the smallest I could make it.

Currently, it makes sure that for each ***category_ref*** and ***service_ref*** in ***sr_cat_rel*** elements, there is a corresponding ***category_code*** and ***service_code*** (located under ***configuration/categories/category*** and ***configuration/service_requests/service_request*** respectively). This is accomplished by the key/keyref pairs under ***configuration***.

The additional constraint that I’m having trouble implementing is the opposite of the one I’ve already implemented; for every ***category_code*** and ***service_code*** , there must be at least one corresponding ***category_ref*** and ***service_ref***. I cannot simply add reversed key/keyref pairs, because having ***category_ref*** and ***service_ref*** as keys requires them to be unique. However, they should not be, unlike ***category_code*** and ***service_code***. They can each **individually** be repeated across ***sr_cat_rel*** elements, but each **pair** is unique. That caveat, along with silly rules in the language, have prevented me from finding a way to implement this constraint, which should not be impossible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://311selfserviceconfig.com" xmlns:tns="http://311selfserviceconfig.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">

        <element name="configuration" type="tns:configuration">
              <key name="categoryCodeKey">
                    <selector xpath="tns:categories/tns:category"/>
                    <field xpath="tns:category_code"/>
              </key>
              <key name="serviceCodeKey">
                    <selector xpath="tns:service_requests/tns:service_request"/>
                    <field xpath="tns:service_code"/>
              </key>
              <keyref name="categoryCodeKeyRef" refer="tns:categoryCodeKey">
                    <selector xpath="tns:service_request_category_relation/tns:sr_cat_rel"/>
                    <field xpath="tns:category_ref"/>
              </keyref>
              <keyref name="serviceCodeKeyRef" refer="tns:serviceCodeKey">
                    <selector xpath="tns:service_request_category_relation/tns:sr_cat_rel"/>
                    <field xpath="tns:service_ref"/>
              </keyref>
       </element>

       <complexType name="configuration">
              <sequence>
                     <element name="categories" type="tns:categories" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
                     <element name="service_requests" type="tns:service_requests" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
                     <element name="service_request_category_relation"
                           type="tns:service_request_category_relation" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
              </sequence>
       </complexType>

       <complexType name="categories">
              <sequence>
                     <element name="category" type="tns:category" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"></element>
              </sequence>
       </complexType>

       <complexType name="category">
              <sequence>
                   <element name="category_code" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
                     <!-- Irrelevant other child elements -->
              </sequence>
       </complexType>

       <complexType name="service_requests">
              <sequence>
                     <element name="service_request" type="tns:service_request" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"></element>
              </sequence>
       </complexType>

       <complexType name="service_request">
              <all>
                     <element name="service_code" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
                     <!-- Misc other child elements -->
              </all>
       </complexType>

       <complexType name="service_request_category_relation">
              <sequence>
              <element name="sr_cat_rel" type="tns:sr_cat_rel" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"></element>
              </sequence>
       </complexType>

       <complexType name="sr_cat_rel">
              <sequence>
                     <element name="category_ref" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
                     <element name="service_ref" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
              </sequence>
       </complexType>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a key/keyref pair to ensure that for every B there is a matching A, and a second key/keyref pair to ensure that for every A there is a matching B.

Detailed code will depend on the details of the structure which you haven't told us about.

Comment: I just added to the question more specific details of my problem

Comment: Thank you for the key/keyref suggestion, it helped me half-solve the problem. But simply having another pair in the other direction wont work in this case because of the uniqueness it implies. See my edits for details.

Comment: With your more detailed statement of requirements, it seems clear that this can't be achieved with XSD 1.0: it needs XSD 1.1 assertions.

Comment: Could you recommend a way to do such a thing with assertions? I am not familiar with them.

Comment: You could write for example `<xs:assert test="every $a in .//a satisfies (some $b in .//b satisfies $a eq $b)"/>`.

Comment: I don't follow. Could you put it in terms of the code I provided?

Comment: I'm not going to give you a personal tutorial on XSD 1.1 in response to your question. If there's a specific thing you can't get working after reading up on it, raise a new question.

Comment: All I asked was for you to rephrase your example in terms of the elements in my code. That would be very helpful to me.

Comment: I didn't do that because I have no idea where `peanutButter` and `jellyCode` appear in the instance document, and what the containing element is that constrains their uniqueness rules.